# What's the most impressive Javascript/Flash/Silverlight example you've seen?

Tags: javascript, flash, silverlight, rich-internet-application

What is the most impressive "rich internet application" -  which is usually Javascript/Flash/Silverlight - that you have experienced?

I find [Google maps](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=area+51+america&sll=51.500969,-0.124583&sspn=0.016082,0.042787&ie=UTF8&z=8) is like Javascript/Flash voodoo and more specifically [Google Streeview](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=houses+of+parliament&sll=51.514285,-0.127845&sspn=0.004186,0.010697&ie=UTF8&ll=51.500969,-0.125098&spn=0,359.957213&z=15&layer=c&cbll=51.500959,-0.124598&panoid=rcPWOI59rSm91p2SwDb32g&cbp=12,170.17,,0,-38.45) wins hands down. But I'm interested to know others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the [Chrome Experiments](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/) are pretty impressive

Comment: Yup, I was going to link that as well. `=)`

Answer (score 5):

http://windows4all.com/

Answer (score 4):

I think [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com/) is pretty impressive!

Answer (score 2):

for me in flash, it's [aviary phoenix](http://aviary.com/tools/phoenix) and [sliderocket](http://www.sliderocket.com/) ...

there are many very cool javascript apps, but the thing is, far too many of them don't degrade well, if at all, which makes it a little pointless to me ... most of the time, they rely on a very specific browser, using features, that have been built in, although far from becoming part of the standard, so it's a) a bit like building a desktop app scripted with JS, and b) you have to face the problem, that the browser of your choice isn't used by the majority of users ... the google suite as it is now, is very impressive (docs, calendar, etc.) and runs in most browsers ... and personally i am quite impressed by TinyMCE, even though it is "only" a text editing component ...

don't know about silverlight ... haven't seen a real killer-app yet, only very impressive proofs of concept, which seems quite astonishing to me, since i thought many .NET apps will be simply adapted/ported to the browser, but either that didn't happen yet, or i missed it ...

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 1):

Quakelight http://www.innoveware.com/quakelight.html and the SL3 gratuitous bouncing plane demo http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/07/21/mix-keynote-bouncing-plane-demo-updated-for-silverlight-3.aspx

Comment: It's a nice demo, but I spawn off the map, then it crashes (and also doesn't work in IE) :

Comment: From the site - "Unfortunately the game is not playable yet."  Works fine in IE8 on Windows 7 RC, maybe its the version you're using?

Comment: I'm on IE8 and Windows 7 (64bit) RC also.

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfenstein 3D in Javascript](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/04/javascript-wolfenstein-3d.html) was pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Super Mario Bros In Flash...

its Awesome...it include different charaters from nintendo like Zelda , Bill Ray (From Contra),and many more...

[check this out](http://supermariobroscrossover.com)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Mario Kart](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/javascript-super-mario-kart.html)!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript demos in http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 0):

The [RPG "JobInterviewStory"](http://www.reddit.com/comments/2dcaxz/_/)

Mostly due to the fact that ALL THAT was done WITHOUT CANVAS. (supposedly)